# Can an array-parameter be declared Constant?

Tags: arrays, c, constants

If I declare a function parameter using array notation (eg: `int a[]`), is there a way to make that pointer constant, so that it cannot be assigned to?

I am referring to the base of the array (eg. the name), and not the data within the array, which can still be non-const.

Please see the comments in the code below.

```
void foo(int *const array) // Array is declared as a Constant Pointer
{
    static int temp[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    array = temp; // This assignment does not Compile, because array is a Constant Pointer, and cannot be assigned.
                  // This is the behavior I want: a Compile Error, to prevent errant assignments.
}

// Array is declared with array[] notation.
// It will decay to a non-const pointer.
// I want it to decay to a const-pointer.
void bar(int array[])
{
    static int temp[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    array = temp;
    // This assignment compiles as valid code, because array has decayed into a non-const pointer.
    // Is there a way to declare parameter array to be a Constant Pointer?
}
```

I'm looking for a way to prevent function `bar` from compiling, while still using the `[]` notation in the parameter list.

Comment: But why would you want to put the implementation details of foo into the interface of foo? Nobody reading the interface would be interested in this. Actually, it makes your interface harder to read w/o any practical use at all.

Comment: I agree that its not a key part of the interface, but the goal is to help prevent programming mistakes by catching any accidental re-assignment of the array inside the function.

Comment: But how would you prevent "programming mistakes" by this? The passed parameter is just like any other variable and can / should be assigned to any other value the programmer wants. If that catches a "programming mistake", you have to make all other variables also const. Because they also could get their value reassigned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the `const` qualifier inside the brackets.  That will apply it to the parameter itself.

```
void bar(int array[const])
```

This is exactly equivalent to your first declaration:

```
void foo(int *const array)
```

As spelled out in section 6.7.6.3p7 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding function declarators:

> A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ shall be adjusted to
> ‘‘qualified pointer to type’’, where the type qualifiers (if any) are
> those specified within the `[` and `]` of the array type derivation.

Comment: I've been programming for years, and never come across that particular syntax before.  Nice!

Comment: Are you sure `int array[const]` isn't the same as `const int *array`? Because otherwise the [const] syntax seems as unintuitive as it gets...

Comment: @hyde Yes, I'm sure.  `const int *array` is the same as `const int array[]`.

Comment: @hyde I guess there was nowhere else to put it.

Comment: It appears that `[volatile]` and `[restrict]` are the only other valid type-qualifers.  Though I don't understand what `[volatile]` might mean in a pass-by-copy language like C.

Comment: Right. TIL. @abelenky `volatile` function parameter forces the argument to be placed in the stack (by the function if it is passed in a register) and then works same as with local variables.

Comment: I recently tried to compile this syntax under MSVC, and got errors.  It seems MSVC probably does not support constant-array pointers this way. (CLang, and GCC are doing it  properly)